# How to override ScrollViewer mouse events?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, scrollviewer

I have a page deliberately set oversize with a ScrollViewer object. Inside this, I have a Canvas object I'm using as a signature box. Basically, the Canvas' MouseMove event draws a line from the old position to the new. Now, this works just fine as far as it goes, but if I scroll, say, a little to the right and attempt this, the Scrollviewer snags it and yanks the screen back left to the origin point, with the effect that my line suddenly jumps to the left, and stays there until I release the mouse button, at which point the screen pops back to where I scrolled it.

I'm already disabling Horizontal/VerticalScrollBarVisibility at the outset of MouseLeftButtonDown, but it still insists on this behavior. It's the same if I scroll down, with the window (and my signature) jumping "up" until I release the mouse.

So basically, is there any way to get ScrollViewer to cut it out, or intercept it in some way, so I can write my signature in peace?

Comment: On what platform are you trying to accomplish this? Wpf or Windows Phone? Take note that wpf isn't used on windows phone (xaml is), but you mention releasing the mouse button as well (which is obviously hard to do on a windows phone).

Comment: Phone 8.1. And I'm using the emulator for debugging, but of course mouseup/down events map to finger up/down on the actual device.